# Creating list of variables x[i,j] in Pyomo model based on certain conditions

Tags: list, variables, pyomo

I am creating a model in Pyomo and I would like to create a binary variable x(i,j) representing links between nodes i and nodes j.

The problem is that not all nodes i are connected to j. Given an already known list of existing links (i,j), I would like to introduce a condition of existence when defining such a variable.

I was wondering if it is possible to initialize the variable from the list or if it is possible to add x[i,j] with a for loop based on an if statement.

```
origin_nodes=[A,B]
dest_nodes=[1,2,3]
list_of_links=[(A,1),(A,2),(A,3),(B,2)]
model.I=Set(initialize=origin_nodes)
model.J=Set(initialize=dest_nodes)
model.X=Var(model.I,model.J, within=Binary)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but see if this documentation is helpful:
https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Sets.html#sparse-index-sets